# Como configurar modo de compatibilidade de .exe pelo prompt?

Tags: cmd, electron

Estou criando uma aplicação em electron, porém as notificações só funcionam se a aplicação estiver rodando no modo de compatibilidade com o windows 7.

Atualmente solicito ao usuário que clique com o botão direito no .exe, vá em propiedades/ compatibilidade/ modo de compatibilidade e altere para windows 7

Preciso saber como realizar a configuração de modo de compatibilidade do executável através do prompt de comando (cmd), pois criarei um arquivo bat para rodar ao executar a aplicação, para que o usuário não tenha que realizar esta atividade manualmente.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajuste o ambiente com o comando

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=WIN98
```

E rode o programa.

As opções são as seguintes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]